# Complement of finitely many vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $F$ be a field and $V$ be a $n$-dimensional vector space over $F$.

For any subspace $W\subseteq V$ we say that $W'$ is a complement of $W$ if
$$ W + W' = V.$$

I have the following question. Consider $W_1,\ldots, W_l$ finitely many subspaces of the same dimension $k$, then prove that there exists a subspace $W'$ of dimension $n-k$ such that it is a complement for all $W_i$.

I have tried by considering basis $B_i$ of $W_i$ and extending to basis of $V$; but I do not really know how to "simultaneously" extend the basis so I can define the complement $W'$.

Comment: Maybe $F$ should be an infinite field? I guess the statement is false otherwise.

Comment: Have you tried a few examples.  For instance, $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, and $W_1$ and $W_2$ the subspaces generated by $e_1$ and $e_2$?  Then $W'$ can be the subspace generated by $e_1 + e_2$.  What if $V = \mathbb{R}^3$ with the same two subspaces?

Comment: I suppose you mean $\;W\color{red}\oplus W'=V$.

Comment: @Bernard, no I did not mean direct sum since I  am not requiring that $W \cap W' $ is trivial.

Comment: This is very unusual. In this case, $V$ itself is a complement of $W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $F$ is an infinite field, oherwise the statement is false.

By (backward) induction on $k$. If $k = n-1$, then pick any vector $v$ such that $v \notin W_j$ for every $j$ and let $W' = \mathrm{Span}(v)$.

Given $W_1, \dotsc, W_l$ of dimension $k$, take any vector $v$ such that $v \notin W_j$ for every $j$, and let $W'_j = \mathrm{Span}(W_j, v)$. Then $\dim W'_j = k+1$, and we apply the induction hypothesis on $W'_j$ to get $W'$ of dimension $n-k-1$ a complement for all $W'_j$. In particular this implies that $v \notin W'$, hence $\mathrm{Span}(W', v)$ is of dimension $n-k$ and is a complement for $W_1, \dotsc, W_l$.

Comment: Thanks @Hugo . Yes $F$ is infinite and I assumed that it was not needed. In fact, it is a crucial assumption.